# Session in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to set and get session in jquery . i have tried this

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script src="Scripts/jquery.session.js"></script>

    Script function 

    success: function (result) {
                        debugger;
                        var m = JSON.parse(result.d).response;
                        console.log(JSON.parse(result.d).response);
                        alert("!2)");
                        debugger;

                        var master = $('#master_table').DataTable({
                            "dom": 'Blfrtip',
                            "columns": [

                                {
                                 "title":" Type",
                                     "data":" Type"
                                }, {
                                    "title": "Frequency",
                                    "title": "Frequency",
                                },

                            ]

                        });
                        for(var i=0;i<m.length;i++)
                        {
                            if (m[i] !== null)
                            {
                                master.row.add({
                                    "Type": m[i][0],
                                    " Frequency": m[i][1]

                                })
                            }
                        } 
                       $.session.set("Type", m[i][0]);
                        $.session.set("Frequency", m[i][1]);
```

i have also added session.js but this is showing error in console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined(…)

Comment: You haven't included the jQuery plugin that supports sessions.

Comment: JQuery Session Plugin address https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin

Comment: @Tushar i add this .. <script src="Scripts/jquery.session.js"></script>

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the plugin and also add `jQuery` before the `session plugin`

**https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin**

Comment: i already add this <script src="Scripts/jquery.session.js"></script>

Comment: @greenuser what is the order of scripts?

Comment: @greenuser Did you check the case in "Scripts" ?

Comment: I mean to say if it is `Scripts` (or) `scripts` ?